# Generalized eigenvalue problem with symmetric positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$SV = TVD$ where $S$ is symmetric positive semi definite, $T$ is symmetric positive definite, $V$ is eigenvector matrix and $D$ is eigenvalue matrix.

In this case, can we guarantee $V$ is orthogonal? i.e. $V^{H} * V = $I?

Comment: Please remember to use MathJAX when posting equations.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is not true in general. You can however prove, that the eigenvectors are $T$- and $S$-orthogonal:

Let $v_i$, $v_j$ be eigenvectors to eigenvalues $\lambda_i\ne\lambda_j$. Then we have
$$
v_i^HSv_j = \lambda_j v_i^HTv_j, \quad v_j^HSv_i = \lambda_i v_j^HTv_i.
$$
Hence it holds,
$$
\lambda_j v_i^HTv_j = \overline{\lambda_i v_j^HTv_i} = \lambda_i v_i^HTv_j,
$$
which implies
$$
v_i^HTv_j = 0.
$$
If both $\lambda_i\ne0$, $\lambda_j\ne0$ then also
$$
v_i^HSv_j = 0
$$
can be proven (with analogous arguments).

Comment: Could the joint eigenvalues (i.e., the elements of $D$) related to the eigenvalues of $S$, $T$? Could it be more easy to find them in that particular case (where $S$, $T$ are symmetric and positive-definite)? Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say. The problem is that eigenvectors of $S$ are hardly eigenvectors of $D^{-1}S$ or $SD$. Maybe you could open a new question with your problem?

Comment: That's what I though! Thanks for your consideration anyway! In fact, I'm interested in a numerical solution (in C, specifically), so that's the way I asked. Thanks again!